# Characters not typed in input field

Tags: html, input

I have a password type `input` field.  When I try to type characters in the `input` field - it does not allow me.

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 control-label no-padding-right text-right">Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg">
    <input id="Password" name="Password" data-type="password" type="text" data-minlength="4" data-maxlength="9" />
    <p id="toMsgError" style="color:red;" class="hide"></p>
    <p id="toMsgSuccess"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: remove data-type="password" and add input type="password"

Comment: *it does not allow me*... this is not reproducible.  please include the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code here that demonstrates the issue you're having.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" data-minlength="4" data-maxlength="9" />
```

If it still doesnt work remove `data-minlength` and `data-maxlength` and try to implement your validation with Javascript.